# How to have a "repeat" statement without an "until" statement using algorithmicx package

Tags: algorithmicx

I'd like to write something very similar to the algorithm shown below, but using the algorithmicx package.  (This example comes from p. 152 of the book [Proximal Algorithms](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/prox_algs.pdf) by Boyd and Parikh.)  How can I have a "repeat" statement without a corresponding "until" statement using algorithmicx?

(I mention the algorithmicx package specifically because I think it's more customizable than other algorithm packages.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using `\algblockdefx` to define a block and then `\algonotext` to suppress typesetting the ending part for the block:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}

\algblockdefx{MRepeat}{EndRepeat}{\textbf{repeat}}{}
\algnotext{EndRepeat}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $sum\gets 0$
\State $i\gets 1$
\MRepeat
\State $sum\gets sum+i$
\State $i\gets i+1$
\EndRepeat
\State $i\gets 100$
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]